# How to develop an iOS application that can run/compile code?

Tags: ios, swift3, cross-compiling

I want to start developing an iOS app that can run Java/C++ that the user inputs. I've seen a lot of iOS apps that can compile C++, Java and other programming languages.

I cannot find anything online to even get me started. Can this be achieved or I need to send the code to a server, compile it and send the response?

Comment: This won't be so easy because it can hit app store policies hard. Writing a compiler is hard. Using a compiler might be very easy.

Comment: I'm not even thinking about writing a compiler. How do I embed a compiler in my app? And how can I restrict it to conform to the app store policies?

Comment: @AnduHD You can embed a compiler as a library. That should tell you everything you need to know.